# How to assign specific substring to column in Python or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to Python. I am trying to understand how I can breakdown a column, by extracting substrings, and the assigning the substrings to a specific column. Please see below on what I want to do:

**Output that I want:**

[image]

So far I have used the following code to break down one column into multiple columns, but this simply breaks down the string into multiple columns but not in the specific order I want. Is there a way to do this with Python?

```py
my_ingredients = my_ingredients.str.split(',',expand = True)
my_ingredients.head()
```

The output I am getting now is as shown below:

**Wrong output which I don't want:**

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can do this with Python?

Thank you!

Comment: I am guessing that `my_ingredients` is the dataframe you're working with. What does it look like before you attempt to modify it? Does it simply only have one column (My_Date) and you would like to split it into three? What would you like these columns to contain? Simply the same name repeated for each row? Could it ever happen that there is ever an element of these columns that is different or is empty? What would those be and when would they happen?

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframe looks like

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"My_Date":["Apple,Cat,Banana","Banana,Cat,Apple","Apple,Banana,Cat","Cat,Apple,Banana"]})

#              My_Date
#  0  Apple,Cat,Banana
#  1  Banana,Cat,Apple
#  2  Apple,Banana,Cat
#  3  Cat,Apple,Banana
```

Then maybe

```py
df = df['My_Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x.split(','))))

#         0       1    2
#  0  Apple  Banana  Cat
#  1  Apple  Banana  Cat
#  2  Apple  Banana  Cat
#  3  Apple  Banana  Cat
```

is what you're looking for. It simply sorts the elements alphabetically.

---

Note, though, that this solution will not place the columns in the right place if there are rows in the original dataframe that aren't a permutation of those three elements. I would imagine that for practical purposes, you might want comma separated values that have varying elements and size. In this case, there may be columns which have elements that are empty. If instead you have a dataframe that looks more like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"My_Date":["Apple,Cat,Banana","Banana,Cat,Apple,","Banana,Cat","Cat,Dog,Apple,Banana"]})

#                       My_Date
#  0           Apple,Cat,Banana
#  1  Banana,Cat,Apple,Elephant
#  2                 Banana,Cat
#  3       Cat,Dog,Apple,Banana
```

Then you could try something like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({e: [e in s.split(',') for s in df['My_Date']] for e in unique_elements})

#     Apple  Banana   Cat    Dog  Elephant
#  0   True    True  True  False     False
#  1   True    True  True  False      True
#  2  False    True  True  False     False
#  3   True    True  True   True     False
```

Or, if you insisted on having the name of the element as the values, then you could go for

```py
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({e: [e if e in s.split(',') else np.nan for s in df['My_Date']] for e in unique_elements})

#     Apple  Banana  Cat  Dog  Elephant
#  0  Apple  Banana  Cat  NaN       NaN
#  1  Apple  Banana  Cat  NaN  Elephant
#  2    NaN  Banana  Cat  NaN       NaN
#  3  Apple  Banana  Cat  Dog       NaN
```

Comment: Hello Jaeden,
Thank you! The last approach really helped. It took me a bit of time to understand how to extract the unique elements that you seem to have defined under 'unique_elements'. I found a good article in Medium about how to extract unique elements in a column from Pandas and used that approach along with yours. It worked out well.